# Kafka connect behaviour in Distribution mode

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Im running Kafka connect in distributed mode having two different connectors with one task each. Each connector is running in different instance which is exactly I want.

Is it always ensure  the same behaviour that Kafka connect cluster share the load properly ?

Comment: Do you mean each connector is running twice? That is not to be expected. Perhaps you can share some more details in your question like the output from the REST API showing the workers and distribution of connectors and tasks?

Comment: I meant each connector running in different instance.  Here the load is shared properly.  Is  it always the same behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connectors in Kafka Connect run with one, or more tasks. The number of tasks depends on how you have configured the connector, and whether the connector itself can run multiple tasks. An example would be the JDBC Source connector, which if ingesting more than one table from a database will run (if configured to do so) one task per table.

When you run Kafka Connect in distributed mode, tasks from all the connectors are executed across the available workers. Each task will only be executing on one worker at one time.
If a worker fails (or is shut down) then Kafka Connect will rebalance the tasks across the remaining worker(s).

Therefore, you may see one connector running across different workers (instances), but only if it has more than one task.

If you think you are seeing the same connector's task executing more than once then it suggests a misconfiguration of the Kafka Connect cluster, and I would suggest reviewing https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/.